# String formatting in python with zip

Tags: python

I sort of understand the zip function,  but what do the accolades in the format() area do in the below code?

Could someone break it all down for me?

```
print('Result: {}'.format({a = b for a,b in zip(l1, l2)}))
```

Comment: Your code has a two syntax errors. `print` should be lowercase and the = is also not accepted by the interpreter. So at the moment this does nothing.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.

Comment: Apologies. I'm on my phone typing this. It's a simplification of a piece of code I read earlier today and it's been bugging me.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `=` into a `:` , so:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]    
print('Result: {}'.format({a : b for a,b in zip(l1, l2)}))
```

This prints a dictionary:

```
{1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 7, 4: 8}
```

The `{<other stuff>}` inside the `format ()` is called a dictionary comprehension, see:

http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_dictionary_comprehension_with_zip_from_list.php

A series of tuples `a, b` are generated successively by iterating through the zipped list and from each tuple `a, b` a key-value pair `a: b` is generated, `a` being the key and `b` being the value.

Comment: Thanks!  Dictionary comprehension is entirely new to me!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong , first print is uppercase , make it lowercase and  `'='` would be `'=='`  , if it is `'=='` then :

Here is an example to make you understand what actually code is doing :

```
{a==b for a,b in zip(l1, l2)}
```

is zipping two list and checking if first element in tuple is equal to second element in tuple :

```
l1=[1,2,3,4,5]
l2=[2,3,3,4,6]

print({a==b for a,b in zip(l1, l2)})
```

output:

```
{False, True}
```